# What is the usage limit to the amount of Polylines that can be drawn on a Google Map (JavaScript V3)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

Is there a set limit to the amount of Polylines I can draw onto a map (Javascript API V3)? As the amount of data I will be applying to the map will be large (100+ Polylines).

Or will I be better off using fusion table layers instead?

The only reason I am not immediately drawn to Google Fusion table layers is that everything is a single layer and can't be styled for each individual Location, but I would accept any help on this matter.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no limit by the API.

But the usage is limited by the environment, because too many features may freeze your browser(what usually doesn't happen with 100 or 200 lines)

However, it's possible to have a individual style for each feature in a FusionTable. e.g. for lines you may specify the strokeColor/strokeWidth in separate columns, so each line my have a different style when you want to.

Comment: How would you then apply the specific styling for each line?

Comment: you must create a map-view, then there will be a button "change feature styles..." when you click on this button a window appears where you may set your style(e.g. by defining the column for the strokeColor). When you create the FusionTablesLayer you must use the styleId of this particular style. You'll get the complete code  for the map-creation(including the styleId) by clicking on the map-Tab->publish->get HTML and javascript. Here is a demo-table: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1TBxGuKa_HFn4Hxm9EfFjyLInh4n8sCpXrOk_zeJF#map:id=3

Comment: Thanks!! Just wanted to know whether or not there is a limit to the amount of individual styles you can have for each location. E.g. If I have 100 kml linestrings can each one be indivdually styled without hitting a limit? Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you use the solution with the column-styles there is no limit(there is only a limit when you apply the style via the styles-option of the FusionTablesLayer)